# Updating elements in a QAbstractListModel from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have a simple QML application.
This application contains a `class ObjectModel : public QAbstractListModel`, which holds a   `ParesisObjectList* mList` containing the data displayed on the GUI.

QML snippet:

```
ListView {
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    model: ObjectModel {
        list: paresisObjectList
    }
    delegate: Text {
        text: type + ": " + identifier + " " + latitude
    }
}
```

The application connects via UDP to a server, which constantly sends new and updated data fields to be displayed on the GUI.
However, there is my problem. I have no issue to insert a new object using the following method which is called whenever a new item was received via UDP:

```
void ParesisObjectList::appendItem(ObjectModelItem item)
{  
    emit preItemAppended();
    mItems.append(item);
    emit postItemAppended();
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to update an Item already existing in `mItems`. I mean, its no issue to change the values, however, I have to notify my GUI somehow to create make sure the value is updated in the GUI as well.

I know, that I have to emit the `dataChanged(...)` signal in the `ObjectModel`, but it is requiring the `QModelIndex` of the position of the updated element.
However, as the update is coming from the C++ side and not trough QML (while calling `bool ObjectModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)`) I have no clue how to get the `QModelIndex` to update the specific value.

Thus, my question is: How can I update the elements in the `ParesisObjectlist` from C++?

Edit:

ParesisObjectList.h

```
struct ObjectModelItem
{
    QString type;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;
    int identifier;
};

class ParesisObjectList : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ParesisObjectList(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QVector<ObjectModelItem> items() const;

    bool setItemAt(int index, const ObjectModelItem& item);
    bool setItem(const ObjectModelItem& item);

signals:
    void preItemAppended();
    void postItemAppended();

    void preItemRemoved(int inex);
    void postItemRemoved();

    void objectUpdated(ObjectModelItem&, int position);

public slots:
    void appendItem(ObjectModelItem);
    void removeItem(int identifier);

private:
    QVector<ObjectModelItem> mItems;
};
```

ParesisObjectList.cpp:

```
ParesisObjectList::ParesisObjectList(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

QVector<ObjectModelItem> ParesisObjectList::items() const
{
    return mItems;
}

bool ParesisObjectList::setItemAt(int index, const ObjectModelItem &item)
{
    if(index < 0 || index >= mItems.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    const ObjectModelItem& oldItem = mItems.at(index);
    if(item.identifier == oldItem.identifier) {
        return false;
    } else {
        mItems[index] = item;
        return true;
    }
}

void ParesisObjectList::appendItem(ObjectModelItem item)
{  
    emit preItemAppended();
    mItems.append(item);
    emit postItemAppended();
}

void ParesisObjectList::removeItem(int identifier)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
        if(mItems.at(i).identifier == identifier) {
            emit preItemRemoved(i);
            mItems.removeAt(i);
            emit postItemRemoved();
        }
    }
}
```

To add an Item to my `ParesisObjectList` I just call `appendItem` which emits the correct signals. However, I have no clue how to update an already existing Item. Eg. if I just want to change the `latitude` or the `longitude` of the object.

Comment: It sounds like your real question is how to make a QModelIndex()?

Comment: So how is the model data set? I can't tell from the way you've written it. I came to the same conclusion as JarMan from reading your question. To get a model index, you can use this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#createIndex

Comment: @JarMan, I'm not sure if I need a QModelIndex or if there might be an other signal to reload the data?

Comment: Please provide more information about `ParesisObjectList`. This is quite easy to do, but details are needed.

Comment: @MarekR I'v added header and source for `ParesisObjectList`

Comment: @eyllanesc I am stuck at same thing. this solution int rowThatChanged = <whatever>
emit dataChanged(index(rowThatChanged), index(rowThatChanged));      the dataChanged method is part  of the the model class so I want to notifiy the model class from list class. how could this be done and only how you got the rowChangedIndex.

Comment: worked for me as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QAbstractListModel gives you a helper function `index()` that creates a QModelIndex based on the row number. So you should be able to use this signal:

```
int rowThatChanged = <whatever>
emit dataChanged(index(rowThatChanged), index(rowThatChanged));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. worked for me as well was stuck on this for a while.